# Кнопки для сообщений телеграм-бота (Python)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, button

Нашел множество статей в интернете как добавлять кнопки(да и в принципе работать с ботом) с импортами разных библиотек для работы с telegram api. Однако я изначально писал бота по статье, не использующую никаких библиотек. И сейчас я хочу добавить кнопки в своего бота. Так вот, есть ли способ это сделать без импортов библиотек для работы с telegram api?

Comment: Ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [ask]

Answer (score 3):

```
URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/sendMessage'
# reply_markup = {"keyboard": [["Yes", "No"], ["Maybe"], ["1", "2", "3"]], "resize_keyboard": True}
# reply_markup = {'inline_keyboard': [[{'text': 'текст1', 'url': 'http://ya.ru'}]]}

reply_markup = {
    'inline_keyboard': [[{'text': 'текст1', 'callback_data': '123'}, {'text': 'текст2', 'callback_data': '1234'}]]}

data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': 'test url', 'reply_markup': json.dumps(reply_markup)}
r = requests.post(URL, data=data, proxies=proxy)
```

Comment: А что такое proxies=proxy?

Comment: например `proxy = {'https': 'socks5h://login:pass@IP:1080'}`